# Is it OK to derive the same class twice in python?

Tags: python, class

I have this code:

```py
class A:
  ...

class B(A):
  ...

class C(B, A):
  ...
```

As you can see, class **C** derives **A** twice, once directly and once indirectly through class **B**.

Is it OK? What possible wrong can happen with this?

Comment: If you have a look at MRO for both B and C then you'll get: `[<class '__main__.B'>, <class '__main__.A'>, <class 'object'>]` for B and `[<class '__main__.C'>, <class '__main__.B'>, <class '__main__.A'>, <class 'object'>]` for C. So there doesn't appear to be any issues that I can see.

Comment: If `B` already inherits `A` is there any need to inherit `A` again in `C`? In case `B` does not inherit `A` and if `C` inherits both the only difficulty you would face is the function `super()` can only be used for the first one **i.e** for only `B` in `class C(B, A):` `super()` can be used and not for `A`

Comment: I know it looks weird. But this code was created by many people with different levels of Python knowledge. That's how this problem appears.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it OK?

Yes. Python will unique out the [MRO](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-method-resolution-order) of `C` to `[C, B, A, object]`, so that the base `A` only appears once. This process is described in [*The Python 2.3 Method Resolution Order*](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/).

> What possible wrong can happen with this?

Someone looking at your code might think *"That's weird. Why are they using multiple inheritance here?"*

It is also possible in more complex situations that Python may have trouble to create a consistent MRO, for example if you had `class C(A, B)` instead of class `C(B, A)` this would be an ambiguous MRO. But you'll know if that ever happens, because there will be a `TypeError` exception during the class definition.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is perfectly ok. It is called multiple inheritence. In other languages, such as C++, this causes an issue called the "diamond problem" because of the shape when you draw a diagram illustrating the inheritance. Python defines a Method Resolution Order (MRO) that solves this problem. I recommend you read about the diamond problem and Python's MRO to understand this better.

Note, the diamond problem involves four classes instead of the three in your example:

```
class A:
  ...

class B(A):
  ...

class C(A):
  ...

class D(C, B):
  ...
```

Comment: I would not say that the MRO solves diamond dependency problems in general. And the OP example is already diamond dep because of the implicit base `object`.

Comment: The question is not about the implicit inheritance of the same class twice but about one implicit and the second explicit inheritance. It is a quite different situation.

Answer (score -2):

- this is known as multiple inheritance.
- However, multiple inheritance can lead to some tricky situations,So try to avoid these cases.
- It's generally recommended to use single inheritance where possible or to use multiple inheritance when it's truly necessary.

Comment: Yes, this is multiple inheritance. However, Python provides a solution to the problems in other languages such as C++.

Comment: As previously commented, Python works with multiple inheritance pretty well. It is not the problem.